# Write quorum for RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ 3.6.5

I have mirroring setup all is working well. I have a question regarding write quorum.

Does a publisher confirm guarantee that the message is written to the mirror or only the master?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [rabbitmq HA doc](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html)

> Mirrored queues support both Publisher Confirms and Transactions. The
>   semantics chosen are that in the case of both confirms and
>   transactions, the action spans all mirrors of the queue.
>   In the case of publisher confirms, a message will **only be confirmed to
>   the publisher when it has been accepted by all of the mirrors**.

Edit :

Transaction Vs Confirm : Both relate to the guarantees regarding the message delivery but differ in the below mentioned ways :-

**Transactions :**

- *Blocking*: the publisher has to wait for the broker to process each message.
- *Needlessly Heavy*: every commit requires a fsync(), which takes a lot of time to complete.

**Confirms**:

- *Asynchronous* : the producer can stream publishes and not wait for the broker. The broker will confirm messages as it processes them and can batch disk writes effectively.

Comment: Just quick question. Does transction and publisher confirm mean the same thing?

Comment: Testing 2 node cluster for simplicity( will have 3 for prod). I created a mirrored queue with HA=Exactly, Count=2 and Sync Mode=Automatic. I downed the second node. But I got no publish faillures. All messages got published and confirmed.